# ASP.NET Authentication Service doesn't works when get published

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, membership-provider, asp.net-authorization

I am developing an **asp.net web project** and I use **ASP.NET authentication service** for it's security system.
As you know, **asp.net** self, creates **aspnetdb** for it's membership and role provider.

Nothing was wrong .

But when I published the website on **IIS**, the authentication system fails.

I thought maybe IIS needs to use SQLServer instead of SQLServerExpress
Then I put my database on a sqlserver on my hosting space and changed the connection strings
and any needed configuration, but yet, the website works correct when I start it from visual studio but it's authentication system fails when I publish it on IIS !

Comment: Can you give use more details? What do you mean it does not work? Are there any errors? Are you using the built in web server in Visual studio or IIS on your dev machine?

Comment: No it doesn't give any error just displays the login page again. when I run the project from visual studio it works correctly but when I publish the website on IIS , authentiation system fails :(